# trouble using time in VB

Tags: excel

I am trying to perform a very simple task. Adding an hour to a cell value using VB.

As a formulae in the sheet, `="D3+TIME(1,0,0)"`, works well.
I have tried the following, plus variations, in VB but nothing has worked so far:

```
Cells(x, y).Value = Cells(x, y).Value + Time(1, 0, 0)
```

returns a type mismatch error.

```
Cells(X, Y).Value = Hour(Cells(X, Y).Value) + 1
```

returns 12:00:00 no matter what's in cells(x,y). Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cells(x, y).Value = Cells(x, y).Value + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
```

[TimeSerial (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)